# Go []byte not getting stored in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, go, byte

I have a MySQL database table with a VARBINARY column called IDs. In Go, I am trying to send a []byte to be inserted into the column called IDs. I did not get an error from the statement.Exec command but when I check the database the column is empty. Any idea why?

Here's my statement

```
statement, _ := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO table(IDs) VALUES (?)")
_, err := statement.Exec(idsByte)
```

Additional info: idsByte was originally a []int32 but I put it through a loop and append the values to a []byte because []int32 is not acceptable to MySQL. Here's how I did the []int32 to []byte conversion.

```
var idsByte []byte
for i:=0;i<len(ids);i++{ //ids is the []int32
    idsByte=append(idsByte,byte(ids[i]))
}
```

If there is a better way to insert an array into a MySQL table, please do share.

Edit: Turns out the []byte is stored, just not visible from Sequel Pro. When I query the row, the column is filled. Anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: This code looks okay on the surface, but it's obviously far from a complete example, so we can't rule out problems elsewhere, like a missing COMMIT, for example. How are you checking the database? Is it possible that your client just doesn't display binary values properly or at all?

Comment: @Peter I'm checking the database by checking Sequel Pro. It's a manual check.

Comment: Encode to hex string `hex.EncodeToString(ids)`, but it's better to use table row per id if you have data per id

Comment: @Eklavya I am required to handle multiple IDs per row. :(

Comment: It's better to create another table with one to many relation and store the ids